# Navigate to Standard Layout or VF page dependent on recordtype

Tags: apex, visualforce

Im using a 'dispatcher' page to direct my users to either a Standard Page or VF page, depending on the recordType. This works fine in terms of sending the user to the correct page, however, if i add a new record for the standard page recordtype, when i hit save it redirects to the same page when i actually want it to redirect back to the parent record. If i hit save again, it then correctly redirects back to the parent, and likwise if i edit a record and save it correctly redirects to the parent. Code below. Grateful for any thoughts as to where im going wrong.

Cheers
Paul

```
public class FinancialPageSelectorController {

private ApexPages.StandardController controller = null;

public FinancialPageSelectorController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}

public PageReference getRedir()
{
    string objId = Financial__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
    string fId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    Financial__c f = [select id, recordTypeId,Site__c,TotalSalesPost__c from Financial__c where Id = :fId];
    string retID = f.Site__c;
    Boolean isNew;
    SYSTEM.DEBUG('sales - ' + f.TotalSalesPost__c);
    if(f.TotalSalesPost__c > 0) 
    {
        isNew = false;
    }else if(f.TotalSalesPost__c == null)
    {
        isNew = true;
    }
    system.debug('IDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD - ' + fid);
    PageReference pr;

    if(f.recordTypeId == SystemUtilities.getRecordTypeId('Store Planning','Financial__c'))
    {
        pr = Page.Financial_Layout_Store_Planning;
    }
    else if(f.recordTypeId == SystemUtilities.getRecordTypeId('IB','Financial__c') || 
            f.recordTypeId == SystemUtilities.getRecordTypeId('IR','Financial__c') ||
            f.recordTypeId == SystemUtilities.getRecordTypeId('CCM','Financial__c') || 
            f.recordTypeId == SystemUtilities.getRecordTypeId('Blackbook','Financial__c') ||
            f.recordTypeId == SystemUtilities.getRecordTypeId('Budget Update','Financial__c') ||
            f.recordTypeId == SystemUtilities.getRecordTypeId('CCM Update','Financial__c'))
    {
        pr = Page.Financial_Layout_Detailed;
    } 
    else if(f.recordTypeId == SystemUtilities.getRecordTypeId('High Level - C','Financial__c') ||
            f.recordTypeId == SystemUtilities.getRecordTypeId('High Level - S','Financial__c') ||
            f.recordTypeId == SystemUtilities.getRecordTypeId('Lockdown - C','Financial__c') || 
            f.recordTypeId == SystemUtilities.getRecordTypeId('Lockdown - S','Financial__c'))
    {
        PageReference prEdit;

            string returnURL = retId;
            system.debug('OLD');
            prEdit = new Pagereference('/' + objId + '/e');
            prEdit.getParameters().put('nooverride','1');
            prEdit.getParameters().put('id',f.id);
            prEdit.getParameters().put('retURL',retId);
            prEdit.getParameters().put('cancelURL',retId);
            prEdit.getParameters().put('saveURL',retId);

        return prEdit.setRedirect(true); 
    }else
    {
        pr = Page.Financial_Layout_Detailed;
    }



    pr.getParameters().put('id',f.id);
    return pr.setRedirect(true);
}

}
```

Comment: What is "standard page recordtype"?

Comment: so the issue is occurring only for where im using the standard pages not the VF pages e.g. the 3rd condition of the IF statement

Comment: Not sure if this would make any difference to the problem your question is regarding...but given how you're using `retID` in that 3rd conditional block you would want to include the preceding slash in its declaration like `String retID = '/' + f.Site__c;`.

Comment: no luck with that, im thinking the easiest way is to just use all VF...

Comment: Can you clarify what you're overriding?  The edit page only? The view page? Both?  Also, what's in f.site__c?  Trimming up your code sample to just the parts relevant to your question may help you get an answer